# Check Specific Time range exists inside the MYSQL table rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-insert, between

[image]

I have one table which contains various start and end DATE-TIME of events. Inside the image, you can see there are different date ranges that are defined for the event as start and end time of the event.

Now when the user going to add the new event then I need to check the time against existing records. I tried with between query but it's not giving me the correct result.

```
Start                  END
2020-07-20 14:15      2020-07-20 15:00   - Not allowed(record #1)
2020-07-20 10:30      2020-07-20 11:00   - Not allowed (record #3)
2020-07-20 11:00      2020-07-20 12:00   - Not allowed(record #3)
2020-07-20 13:00      2020-07-20 14:00   - Allowed
```

How can I get at least count of duplicate(Not allowed) records based on above all conditions in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure that newly inserted rows do not overlap existing intervals. One option is `not exists`:

```
insert into mytable (start, end)
select v.*
from (select '2020-07-20 14:15' start, '2020-07-20 15:00' end) v
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t
    where t.start <= v.end and t.end >= v.start
)
```